# Pagination using PageObject Watir Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

[image: Table]

I am trying to click a link using the following method, but the link exists in second page of the table rather than the first.  I was wondering how can I make the method generic by searching the link in all the pages of the table and clicking the desired link?

table(:grid){ div_element(:class => 'flexigrid')
  .table_element(:id => 'segmentGridContainer') }

```
def click_edit_link(name,label)

  date = Time.now.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
  label_text = label + date
  grid_element.cell_element(:text => /#{label_text}/)
  .parent
  .link_element(:text => name )
  .click

end
```